# Sorting Arraylist for a string but only by date

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist that contains `"2013-7-13 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s) "` such kind of records. how can i sort this only by date.

piece of code:

```
String date1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabProDB.KEY_DATE) );
String time1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabProDB.KEY_TIME) );
String date_time1 = date1 + "\n" +time1;
Toast.makeText(History.this, date_time1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
listItems.add(date_time1);
```

Comment: Use a custom class!! A class that contains **both** **Date object** and string representation of the date

Comment: is it arraylist of timestamp or is it arraylist of object which has timestamp as one of its property.

Comment: In the millennium compare object one by one.

Comment: Given the structure above you can simply use a Comparator<String> that simply calls the compare() method of the String argument. Have a look at Collections.sort(list,comparator);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `Comparator<String>` implementation, something like the following:

Note that there are no error checks, it's just to show you how you could do it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> strings =
        Arrays.asList("2013-7-13 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s)",
            "2013-7-10 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s)");

    Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date date1;
        Date date2;
        try {
          date1 = format.parse(o1.split(" ")[0]);
          date2 = format.parse(o2.split(" ")[0]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse date!", e);
        }

        return date1.compareTo(date2);
      }
    });


    System.out.println(strings);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although u should have followed Object Oriented Style by making passing date and time as class object... and making a Arraylist out of this class..
Anyways... This code might help u out!

> Remember String comparison and Date and Time comparison are two
>   different things, you can also refactor below code as per ur needs

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int result = o1.compareTo(o2);
        return result;
    }
}
```

> ```
> Now use Collection.sort method
> ```

```
List<String> dateTimeList = new ArrayList<String>
Collections.sort(dateTimeList, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: sorry, why do I need dateTimeList here? I already have a list called "listItems"

Comment: @user2799726 its just a variable name as in your code date_time1 is a concatenation of both date and time ...

Answer (score 0):

Array.sort can be passed a custom comparator. If you know for a fact that all your string are exactly the same format, simply create your comparator based on the substrings.

You could also implement your own sort, but that is not ideal as Java already provides the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that you can try doing...

-- > If you are sure that "\n" is available in each entry **say y** then get date part only from each entry using *org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBefore(String, String)* **say x**

--> Next step is to parse x to Date using *java.text.SimpleDateFormat* **(yyyy-mm-dd)**

--> You can then use any collection object that can contain key and value pair, where key is x and value y (use **TreeMap** this can automatically sort the value.)

**Problem with this approach**: this approach will not work if part x is common in more than one entry for your array.

---

Try to run this code. The last print statement will give you sorted result. The values inside map is what you are looking for.

```
class TestClass {
    public void checkThis() throws ParseException {
        String[] sampleValues = new String[3];
        sampleValues[0]= "2013-7-13 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s) ";
        sampleValues[1]= "2013-8-14 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s) ";
        sampleValues[2]= "2013-5-16 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s) ";
        System.out.println("--> before"+ sampleValues);

        String x= null;
        Date date =null;
        Map<Date, String> map = new TreeMap<Date, String>();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        for (String y : sampleValues) {
            x = StringUtils.substringBefore(y, " \n");
            date= formatter.parse(x);           
            map.put(date, y);
        }

        System.out.println(map.keySet());
    }
}
```

Comment: it might get the problem you said. cuz the "x" which is, for example, "12 hour(s) 23 minute(s)" will have duplicate records.

Comment: that may work. Could you give me some actual code, i'm not familiar with treemap, thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Step one***

Parse your `String` into an actual `Date` object`:

```
final String s = "2013-7-13 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s)";
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd \n hh 'hour(s)' 23 'minute(s)'");
final Date d = sdf.parse(s);
```

**Do not store your dates as strings**.

***Step two***

Put all those new `Date`s into your `List` and call `Collections.sort`.

At any point later your can use the same `SimpleDateFormat` (or a totally different one) to format your `Date` back into a `String`:

```
final String form = sdf.format(d);
System.out.println(form);
```

Output:

> 2013-7-13 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s)